# Failed to import CA to cacert using Sun's Code

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool, ca

I'm trying to make my program that could add self-signed CA from remote into local Java trust keystore.

(Yeah, I know this is dangerous and I talks, but THEY don't bother, so don't bother to tell me "This is dangerous" too. What I can do is just make a "switch" in the config properties so this function could be switch off when they don't need to use it.)

The code that I'm using is coming from this link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130319003303/http://dzone.com/snippets/ssl-download-certificate-chain

I made a little modify that this program will choose first CA displayed on screen(at line 107, and it looks like the Right CA from remote that I need when I run it.), and I thought it should add the CA into cacerts automatically but No. It generated an file call "jssecacerts" at the folder where I run this program, and my own program still popping "PKIX build path failed".

So... assume that this is the right program that I need, how could that "jssecacerts" would help me to solve my issue? could I name it as "cacert" and replace the original one?

Comment: I don't think that changing the code to replace the cacert file will work they way you are thinking it will.  I'm fairly confident that the cacert/jssecacerts file(s) are only read at runtime of your application.  I think you will want to look into managing the keystore in memory.  You could also consider just turning off the checking of certificates: `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false`

Comment: Do you want to trust this cert *for SSL/TLS (including HTTPS)* or other things? `jssecacerts` _in JRE/lib/security directory_ where the code you link puts it (not necessarily where you run it) is the default truststore only for SSL/TLS. If you have more than one version or copy of Java installed, make sure you use the correct JRE home. Make sure the application uses the default, i.e. the code doesn't use an explicit store and sysprops `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` are not set. @hooknc: checkRevocation only affects checking of revocation, not the rest of cert checking.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you're right about checkRevocation, I thought that there was a system parameter that could be set that basically stopped all checking of certificates and allowed any certificate that was encountered.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So I have to drag it and put it into JRE's security folder? hmm... is there any other way that I don't need to switch off CA checking and accept the self-signed SSL CA connection via code?

Comment: Oops! I didn't read to the end; the program you linked _reads_ from JRE/lib/security but _writes_ to the current directory. So yes, you need to move the new `jssecacerts` back to JRE/lib/security; dragging is one way. *If* your code uses (or is changed to use) an explicit `SSLContext` you can give that context something that `implements TrustManager` and accepts any cert you wish, or any at all; of course that is even more insecure than a selfsigned but known cert.